# Total table column with jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have found on this site a jquery function for updating a table row. Now  I need the total for the column. Anybody? I,m not familiar with jquery and tried  a lot of things but don't get it working.

Fiddle:   http://jsfiddle.net/heliosh/r7dvay4o/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function updateArticle1() {
        var Persons = parseFloat($("#dare_price1").val());
        var total = (Persons) * 2.00;
        var total = total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total_price_amount1").val(total);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price1", updateArticle1);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    function updateArticle2() {
        var Animals = parseFloat($("#dare_price2").val());
        var total = (Animals) * 3.50;
        var total = total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total_price_amount2").val(total);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price2", updateArticle2);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    function updateArticle3() {
        var Bedlinen = parseFloat($("#dare_price3").val());
        var total = (Bedlinen) * 8.50;
        var total = total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total_price_amount3").val(total);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price3", updateArticle3);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    function updateArticle4() {
        var Towels = parseFloat($("#dare_price4").val());
        var total = (Towels) * 7.50;
        var total = total.toFixed(2);
        $("#total_price_amount4").val(total);
    }
    $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price4", updateArticle4);
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Persons?</td>
        <td>
            <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price1" name="Persons" value="" size="30" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Animals?</td>
        <td>
            <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price2" name="Animals" value="" size="30" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bedlinen?</td>
        <td>
            <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price3" name="Bedlinen" value="" size="30" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Towels?</td>
        <td>
            <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price4" name="Towels" value="" size="30" type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 50%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 403px"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 403px">Rentalprice</td>
        <td>189.00</td>
        <td>Euro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 403px">Taxes</td>
        <td style="width: 50px">
            <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount1" readonly="readonly" name="PricePersons" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>Euro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 403px"><span lang="nl">Animals</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount2" readonly="readonly" name="PriceAnimals" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>Euro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 403px"><span lang="nl">Bedlinen</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount3" readonly="readonly" name="PriceBedlinen" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>Euro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 403px"><span lang="nl">Towels</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount4" readonly="readonly" name="PriceTowels" value="" />
        </td>
        <td>Euro</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 403px">Total</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Euro</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you're not familiar with jQuery, you should take some time to learn it.

Comment: Why are you using document.ready multiple times? just wrap everything in a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7dvay4o/2/).

I calculates the grand total of all the items.

Here is the snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function updateArticle1() {
    var Persons = parseFloat($("#dare_price1").val());
    var total = (Persons) * 2.00;
    var total = total.toFixed(2);
    if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;
    $("#total_price_amount1").val(total);
  }


  function updateArticle2() {
    var Animals = parseFloat($("#dare_price2").val());
    var total = (Animals) * 3.50;
    var total = total.toFixed(2);
    if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;
    $("#total_price_amount2").val(total);
  }


  function updateArticle3() {
    var Bedlinen = parseFloat($("#dare_price3").val());
    var total = (Bedlinen) * 8.50;
    var total = total.toFixed(2);
    if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;
    $("#total_price_amount3").val(total);
  }


  function updateArticle4() {
    var Towels = parseFloat($("#dare_price4").val());
    var total = (Towels) * 7.50;
    var total = total.toFixed(2);
    if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;
    $("#total_price_amount4").val(total);
  }


  function updateTotal() {
    var price1 = parseFloat($("#total_price_amount1").val());
    var price2 = parseFloat($("#total_price_amount2").val());
    var price3 = parseFloat($("#total_price_amount3").val());
    var price4 = parseFloat($("#total_price_amount4").val());
    var total = price1 + price2 + price3 + price4;
    if (isNaN(total)) total = 0;
    $("#totalSum").text(total);
  }

  $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price1", updateArticle1);
  $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price2", updateArticle2);
  $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price3", updateArticle3);
  $(document).on("change, keyup", "#dare_price4", updateArticle4);
  $(document).on("click", "#getTotal", updateTotal);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Persons?</td>
    <td>
      <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price1" name="Persons" value="" size="30" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Animals?</td>
    <td>
      <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price2" name="Animals" value="" size="30" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bedlinen?</td>
    <td>
      <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price3" name="Bedlinen" value="" size="30" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Towels?</td>
    <td>
      <input class="span4 input-big" id="dare_price4" name="Towels" value="" size="30" type="text" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table style="width: 50%">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 403px"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 403px">Rentalprice</td>
    <td>189.00</td>
    <td>Euro</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 403px">Taxes</td>
    <td style="width: 50px">
      <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount1" readonly="readonly" name="PricePersons" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>Euro</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 403px"><span lang="nl">Animals</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount2" readonly="readonly" name="PriceAnimals" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>Euro</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 403px"><span lang="nl">Bedlinen</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount3" readonly="readonly" name="PriceBedlinen" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>Euro</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 403px"><span lang="nl">Towels</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input style="border: 0px;" class="style11 span4 input-big" id="total_price_amount4" readonly="readonly" name="PriceTowels" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>Euro</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 403px">Total</td>
    <td id="totalSum">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Euro</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="getTotal" type="button" value="Get Total" />
```

This code can be further optimized by replacing the 4 functions `replaceArticle1()`, `replaceArticle2()`, `replaceArticle3()`, `replaceArticle4()` with just a single function `replaceArticle()` and updating the respective elements using their `id`s.

Answer (score 0):

There is your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/51184zv6/)

You need to add an id to your Rentalprice value to use it in your script:

```
<td style="width: 403px">Rentalprice</td>
<td><span id="rental_price">189.00</span></td>
```

In handlers for each input field you should call `updateTotal()` function in the end.

If value of input is not a number, just set `''` as a value.

Comment: Thanks for the script. It's great. Now i tried instead input a select box for 1 to 5 persons. But it will not work.